# IoT Standards for data format when uploading to clouds or servers

Tags: standards, data-portability

What are some IoT Standards that provide a *format* or *framework* for representing data to be sent to cloud?

The problem often faced is:

> one tends to have information from sensor nodes and edge nodes but the data pushed to cloud often times lacks context or semantic meaning. An example, where temperature measured by a sensor node might just have a timestamp and values but does not mention which sensor node produced it and what the context of the measurement is (if unit is C or K or F) etc.

I went searching for some representation standards and have come across only a couple as of now:

1. [SenML from IETF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8428)
2. [Web of Things from W3C](http://model.webofthings.io/)

Although they look relatively simple, implementation and examples are hard to come by.

I am looking for similar standards that can bunch the different sources of data and push that information to the cloud where it might be saved persistently with more context and maybe portable to other platforms for future usage.

Answer (score 2):

My son implemented a cloud database system for us to share.  It accepts blobs of JSON data presented by IOT devices and does some parsing on the JSON data to facilitate lookups from the DB.  The header information is also JSON.  The JSON blob is one field in the header.

This is not a standard, but it is serviceable.

If you are using a commercial site, they may have their own format you must follow.  Whatever it is, just use it.  None of this is hard to write, and not fighting uphill against a standard makes everything easier.